# Bind Selected li element click event to a prototype function

Tags: jquery

## Update code modified

I am trying to extend jQuery plugin to add custom functionality, element has ul and which has several li elements (li will be added by this plugin itself), i am trying to get clicked li element html

```
var Fileupload = function (element, options) {
    this.$element = $(element)
    this.$list = this.$element.find("ul li")
}

  Fileupload.prototype = {

    listen: function () {
        $(this.$list).on('click',$.proxy(this.click,this)) // i guess error could be here
  }
    click: function(e){
     this.$img = e.target;
        var test = this.$img;
        if($(test).attr("src"))
        {
            $(test).closest("li").append("<button class='btn btn-mini'>Remove</button>")
        }
  }
}
```

Note : I am using bootstrap fileupload plugin, i want to maintain the structure of code and i am not fond of

```
.find("ul li").click(//my code here}
```

Comment: look at the `event` object that is the first parameter (`e`) in the handler.  You'd want either the `target` or `currentTarget` member of that object.

Comment: @MattWhipple Thanks a lot works. I have updated the code. Please have a look at click function let me know i can improve coding standards.

Comment: You likely shouldn't change the question text so that it is no longer a question.  I'm the wrong person for that type of coding style since I prefer the more functional style JavaScript, though I would say:
 don't assign variables you're not using (`$element`;) be careful about the jQuery wrappers (`$img` should likely be a wrapper and then that would prevent the wrapping afterward); and don't give variables a larger scope than necessary, particularly when they could introduce future concurrency issues (`$img` doesn't look like it needs to be anything more than a local variable).

Comment: Also if you're expecting the `click` to be associated with an `img` you should add the selector to the `on` binding.  And one more...if the handler doesn't need to have references to `this` (which it appears not to), you can drop the use of `proxy`.  If you do need `this` and `this` remains fixed, then using `bind` would likely be more intentional and (less importantly) portable.  And you probably shouldn't name members with what could be confused with keywords (like `click`), pick a more semantic function name.